# Azure created ARM is not valid in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-resource-manager

I create a resource an Azure CosmosDB resource in a Sandbox resource group. 
 That works great!

I then go to "Automation Script".

1) First Problem, these errors are output:

```
Export template operation completed with errors. Some resources were not exported. Please see details for more information. (Code: ExportTemplateCompletedWithErrors)

Could not get resources of the type 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/managementPolicies'. Resources of this type will not be exported. (Code: ExportTemplateProviderError, Target: Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/managementPolicies)
Could not get resources of the type 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices'. Resources of this type will not be exported. (Code: ExportTemplateProviderError, Target: Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices)
Could not get resources of the type 'Microsoft.Web/sites/premieraddons'. Resources of this type will not be exported. (Code: ExportTemplateProviderError, Target: Microsoft.Web/sites/premieraddons)
Could not get resources of the type 'Microsoft.Web/sites/sourcecontrols'. Resources of this type will not be exported. (Code: ExportTemplateProviderError, Target: Microsoft.Web/sites/sourcecontrols)
```

2) I then download the JSON to a local file and save it, "./myTemplate.json". I go to "Templates" on the Azure portal, and add the JSON in myTemplate.json.

3) Second problem, I cannot validate the template.

In the Templates section, I select my Template, and can view the JSON (that was provided by Azure), and then select `Deploy`.  (Shouldn't there be a `Validate` in addition to `Deploy`?)

Deploy takes me to a "Custom Deployment" view in the Azure portal.  I follow the steps, and select `Purchase` which is when the template gets validated.

```
Deployment template validation failed: 
'The template resource '[variables('databaseAccounts_gsdev_name')]' at 
line '62' 
and column '9' is not valid: Evaluation result of language expression 
'[variables('databaseAccounts_gsdev_name')]' is type 'Object', expected 
 type is 'String'.. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions 
 for usage details.'. (Code: InvalidTemplate)
```

I also reported this problem on the Azure DevOps website:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/408898/azure-created-arm-is-not-valid-in-azure.html

Why is Azure unable to create a valid template from a resource that it is currently supporting?

Comment: #1 Your first problem "Resources of this type will not be exported" means that resource is not available to be created using ARM templates. #3 You say you "cannot validate the template" are you getting an error? If it's no validating it's not correct. #4 An invalid template is not going to allow a deploy.

Comment: #1 should not occur in the first place, IMO.  I can create the resource via the portal, but Azure cannot create an ARM template to support that resource?  That is a big inconsistency.

#3 I tried to provide more detail.  Thanks for bringing that up.

Comment: you can test this by going to the portal select a resource and then the automation blade. You will see a notification at the top of the template notifying you that some of the resource are not available to be deployed via ARM template. As far as whether this should even be an issue....I have to agree with you. The best you can do is remove the resources and deploy them post ARM template deployment via scripting or portal.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't resolve the issue but helps creating valid and more readable templates faster.

Take templates for desired services from [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates) and then just copy the values and fill extra settings that are not included in the template. I would not recommend to use the automation script functionality as base for template anyway since it has tons of unnecessary lines which makes the ARM-template more difficult to read and understand.

Comment: We started using this and building the ARM templates has been much easier.  However, in regards to the question, the portal should not be creating erroneous templates.

Answer (score 0):

1) I see the error all the time. Using **Automation script** to export ARM templates becomes nearly useless for more complicated configuration, especially with resource extensions. I've seen the same problems reported (e.g. https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas/issues/148).

3) Use double-quotes on the outermost string.
The error message has:

`'[variables('databaseAccounts_gsdev_name')]'`

Try changing that to:

`"[variables('databaseAccounts_gsdev_name')]"`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and link.  The double quotes does not change anything.  Luckily, I use Prettier in VSCode and that change happens automatically on save for me.

Comment: Can you upload or show the ARM template? That would help to troubleshoot.

BTW, I'm using 'Azure Resource Manager Tools' for VS Code and love it.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msazurermtools.azurerm-vscode-tools

Answer (score 0):

1) happens when the template schemas for the resource are missing - we're working on filing the gaps here so this should be less common once that happens.

3) looks like a bug in the export or the schema (probably the latter).  if I'm guessing right that var is used for the name of a db?  The name property is defined as a string (JSON type) and the variable was exported as an object?  If you can the template, it should help troubleshoot.

Comment: 2023 and the first error is still occurring. Granted, I'm trying to export a rather large resource group with all resources, but still, it has been 5 years.